# Выборка выводит данные обо всех, а не об одном

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день! Делаю выборку:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `alerts` WHERE `whom`='$user' AND `type`='3' OR `type`='4' OR `type`='5' OR `type`='6'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Ожидаю получить всё из базы, где пользователь = $user и типы 3, 4, 5, 6, НО выводит не об одном пользователе, а о всех, - в  чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `alerts` WHERE `whom`='$user' AND (`type`='3' OR `type`='4' OR `type`='5' OR `type`='6')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Группировку условий надо использовать